Multi-module maven application Dockerfile problem
My goal would be that I create 3 services.
1 for the DB
1 for the main application (depends on DB)
1 for testing purposes (depends on main application)
First I would like to do this with just 2 services. It is a multi-module project and I would like to keep this structure:
webservices [parent webservices]  (this is the pom project)
├── app_webservices/
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
│
└── pom.xml

The Dockerfile for the web application would be something like this if it wasn't a multi-module project:
FROM maven:3.9.7-eclipse-temurin-11 AS builder

WORKDIR . /app

COPY . /app

RUN mvn clean package

FROM tomcat:9.0.89-jre11-temurin-jammy

COPY --from=builder /app/target/*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

This is the docker-compose file:
services:
  db:
    image: buildo/h2database:latest
    container_name: database
    restart: "always"
  app:
    build: app_webservices
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    container_name: application
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./h2-data:/usr/local/tomcat/h2-data

Based on the documentation, COPY, ADD, etc can't go outside the build context, so for example COPY ../pom.xml ../ would become something like COPY pom.xml . . The problem is that Dockerfile should see the parent pom in the case of this structure. It can be solved if I put the Dockerfile(s) in the root. But is it solvable if I would like to keep the structure mentioned above?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

If you specify build: { context: ., dockerfile: app_webservices/Dockerfile } then you can COPY pom.xml ./ from the top-level directory and COPY app_webservices/pom.xml app_servervices from the application subdirectory.
